# Нужна помощь при создании ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Извините за кривой рисунок) Есть главный viewController (справа), в его navigation есть button, при нажатии которого с левой стороны появляется новая viewController2 (слева) и закрывает главный viewController не полностью, а оставляет 10% по ширине (там заштриховано). Получается наложение одного viewController на другой.

1. Как настроить, чтобы этот viewController2 появлялся с левой стороны?
2. Как сделать, чтобы он не менял viewController, а лишь накладывался на главный?

Comment: Во всех своих проектах где мне нужно использовать боковой бар я использую библиотеку `SWRevealViewController` вот [ссылка](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController). Удачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В комментарии все верно написано, используй SWRevealViewController
2. Используй `presentViewController` он не будет выгружать из памяти начальный View Controller. А чтобы вернуться обратно `dismissViewController`